# Recyclerview inside NestedScrollView - Know position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Im using recycler view inside nested scrollview .

**Since** : I have to use reycler view inside NestedScrollView

Problem is :

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PersonViewHolder v, final int position){

        // Other Codes here

        if(position >= getItemCount()-5){
            // HERE IS MY PROBLEM
        }
    }
```

My Adapter codes :

```
public static class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.PersonViewHolder>{
    List<News> news;

    RVAdapter(List<News> news){
        this.news = news;
    }

    public class PersonViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CardView cv;
        ImageView profile_image_chat;
        TextView name;
        TextView city;

        PersonViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
            profile_image_chat = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image_chat);
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            city = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.city);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount(){
        return news.size();
    }



    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PersonViewHolder v, final int position){

        Picasso.with(con).load(news.get(position).image).resize(500,500).centerCrop().transform(new CircleTransform()).into(v.profile_image_chat);
        v.name.setText(news.get(position).title);
        v.city.setText(news.get(position).city);

        v.cv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){

                /* Intent intent = new Intent(con , agahi.class);
                int id = news.get(position).id;
                intent.putExtra("id" ,id+"" );
                con.startActivity(intent); */

            }
        });

        if(v.getAdapterPosition() >= getItemCount()-5){
            Log.e("scrolling" , "ok");
            // fill_shops();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public PersonViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int arg1){
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_chats, viewGroup, false);

        PersonViewHolder pvh = new PersonViewHolder(v);
        return pvh;
    }

}
```

I cannot get postion in `onBindViewHolder()` . I have to know position and get new lists .

How can do this ?

Comment: What are you getting in position variable?

Comment: @AshishTiwari Im getting it for new request to server and receive other data

Comment: "I cannot get postion in onBindViewHolder()" What does it means

Comment: @AshishTiwari I mean its always equals with getitemcount() . and if(true)

Comment: Please share your your adapter's code and Activity/Fragment code where your are you using adapter

Comment: @AshishTiwari i added adapter codes here

Answer (score 0):

Use `getAdapterPosition()` method to get position if your are using `ViewHolder` class...

```
final int pos = holder.getAdapterPosition();
```

Comment: ok...just try to print v.getAdapterPosition()  value. Check what is giving actually.